# Laravel Voyager Storage link issue

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I have used custom directory structure to install laravel on xampp. public folder's content is in the `htdocs/demos/sricargo/` folder

[image]

And rest of the files and folders are in same level of the htdocs and in this folder

[image]

I have managed to get laravel working with this folder structure. But after I installed voyager, In voyager dashboard it gives me this error

> Missing storage symlink
>   We could not find a storage symlink. This could cause problems with loading media files from the browser.

When I press the fix button it then gives this error

> Could not create missing storage symlink
>   We failed to generate the missing symlink for your application. It seems like your hosting provider does not support it.

This is the `.htaccess` file located in the `htdocs/demos/sricargo/` folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Options +FollowSymLinks

    RedirectMatch ^/$ /wp-blog/
    Redirect "/demos/sricargo/blog" /wp-blog/

    RewriteBase /demos/sricargo/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /demos/sricargo/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I even tried to created the symlink with `php artisan storage:link` command but it gives this error

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
>   The [public/storage] directory has been linked.

When I create a new folder in media page and uploaded a new image file it's actually uploaded in this location `sricargo_files\storage\app\public\`

So the images thumbnail are not displaying in the media page and when i click `public url` link in media page it gives this url `http://localhost/demos/sricargo/storage/app/public/bb/0U1TwmFxLcJ833ufKOSV4nrJlZs9QvZVb7yjEwq7.jpeg` ('bb' is the newly created folder through media page). Even though this storage folder doesn't exist on this path `htdocs/demos/sricargo/`

How can this be resolved ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

you can set custom directory indeed, but the custom directory's location should be in your app directory for local development. If you make changes to your directory structure, php artisan command will not work